# Convergence of Value Iteration for Discount factor of 1

Tags: markov-decision-process, convergence, value-iteration, discount-factor

Given this pseudo code for value iteration:

[image]

In the case of gamma=1, under what conditions on the MDP will we still be able to find the optimal policy?

Comment: The value iteration algorithm is an algorithm for solving the Bellman optimality equation, which has a unique solution only if $\gamma<1$. When $\gamma=1$ many definitions including state value are invalid. They need new definitions and the Bellman equation becomes the Poisson equation. Some contents about the undiscounted case can be found in Section 9.3.2 here, though it is about policy gradient methods instead of value iteration: https://github.com/MathFoundationRL/Book-Mathmatical-Foundation-of-Reinforcement-Learning

Comment: The pseudocode as given is broken for $\gamma = 1$ (and technically for $\gamma = 0$, although that is more fixable) due to the condition in the repeat until loop. So could you clarify whether you really meant to ask about the specific pseudo-code given, or about convergence of value iteration in general when $\gamma=1$?

Comment: @NeilSlater Hi, yes sorry, the pseducode is not defined for gamma = 1. I meant for value iteration in general. Would a condition on the MDP / environment that states that we always reach a final state, would mean that value iteration will give us the optimal policy?